# bootstrap navbar collapse with scroll bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the css code bellow to collapse the navbar at 930px. The code works nicely except for one thing, it doesn't add the scroll bar for more navigation links. How can I add the scroll bar so that the last navigation links only appear when you scroll within the dropdown list? Note that the scroll bar is there for xs screens but not there for screens between 930 and 768 px.

HTML

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#services">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#carousel1">Welcome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team-members">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
/*
    Collapse Navbar between 930px and 768px
*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 930px) {
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
        margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jusdtggL/)

Comment: Can you add your code in fiddle please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please try adding this

you can set max height whatever you want

```
#topFixedNavbar1
{
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

if i miss something let me know in comment

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfect. I added

#topFixedNavbar1 {
overflow-y: scroll !important;
}